# Python : Help for windows OS interface styling on fly

Tags: windows, python-3.x, user-interface, user-interaction

I want to write a application to ***control windows interface with a joystick***.
So this will work as console application. Will control user interactions and emulate keyboard controls via Joystick inputs.
I can switch between applications, I can move the pointer through elements

**Example :** I have Firefox and vlc player is active
I can switch from firefox to Vlc player then back to Firefox with emulating ALT+TAB

In Firefox : When i move pointer through elements of the page in Firefox using TAB, Each element is highlighted with **dotted outline**.

When i click ALT on firefox, "File" menu is highlighted
But also highlighted with **dotted outline**.

Is there a library/ is there a way in python to change style of pointed/active element globally on fly on windows interfaces, so active element will be easily recognized?

Answer (score 0):

Try PyUserInput for generating keypress events / Mouse Control in python.
https://github.com/PyUserInput/PyUserInput